# How to make a user in the administrator view only the content created by the same? django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am implementing user can manage, and could achieve only create new users without the staff, super administrator, groups, permissions, but I can not make users see only the make, do not see the users created by me or by another user.

I leave here, as was done so that users could create users without changing permissions:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def queryset(self,request):
        qs = admin.ModelAdmin.queryset(self,request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        # Sólo permitir la visualización/edición de usuarios que no son superusuarios
        return qs.filter(is_superuser=False)
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        # Denegar edicion de: staf, super usuario, grupos, permisos
        return () if request.user.is_superuser else ('is_staff','is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Question is too complicated. You want to create users that cannot see any user that they dont create in Admin Page. right?

Comment: exact, if you give another user to be managed independently, I do not want him to see what I do, but if you want to see what the user does or creates. as you would?